# Excel Autocomplete/lookup that I can edit

Tags: excel

I have a system where I enter a code in one cell and in the next cell the corresponding text appears, using a lookup table.

Cell 1: I put "W1"
Cell 2: "Make sure that both your opening and ending are interesting and engaging." appears automatically.

Of course, I can't then edit the text.  If I try, I find I'm editing the lookup formula.

What I'm really trying to do:
I'm a teacher, the codes are target codes and the text is the actual advice to the pupil.  We have a standard system of targets, but we tend to customise the text in different ways according to the pupil.

Am I doing this the most sensible way?  Is there a workaround?

Many thanks.

Comment: Well,it seems to be working as desired :) If so it sounds fine, if you need to make it more complex then more examples would help us recommend if your approach could be improved.

Comment: Well no it isn't.  Once the Target text has been 'looked up' I need to edit it, but I can't.  For example, two students might get a target to check their spelling carefully, but I might want to edit the text after it's been 'lookedup' to include a particular spelling that they should focus on.

Comment: Well you either need (1) a larger lookup-list with sub-options. (2) Or add manual entries to cell 3 in support of cell 2

Comment: Well, I couldn't do the sub-options bit because there are an infinite number of possible customisations a teacher might want to make to the standard target.  For example a target "Make sure that you check your spelling carefully" could be edited to include specific words that that pupil struggled with - I can't have a different code for every potential word in the language.  I'm currently doing your second option, but I was really hoping that there might be a way to do this.  Would VBA help?

Comment: Ed, VBA can help if there is an obvious pattern to follow to remove the manual work. For example, if the student test results were captured somewhere, and the incorrect entries could be automatically flagged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires, as far as I understand it, VBA.  Thanks to those below for helping me figure that out.

The answer is here:

[VBA Lookup and insert on cell change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261549/vba-lookup-and-insert-on-cell-change)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's not you're looking for, but try the following:

1. Put all grades in the column 1 (corresponds to your cell 1).
2. Apply Lookup formula and get default answers - this for the column 2.
3. Now copy entire column 2 and **paste special it** as `values` to the same place.

After the above you'll get default grades as TEXT ready for your editing.

Please respond in comments in case you have some more not obvious (from the initial request) limitations.

Comment: That's what I would do, but I need to make this easy for everyone in my department to do.  I can't ask them to enter the code to get the basic text, then copy and paste special to get it in text form so that they can edit if they want to, for each individual target.  It would be more effort than just writing all targets manually.  Any idea how I can get it returned as text?

Comment: Just another immediate idea: is that ok to copy and special paste both columns **to new worksheet as values**? Seems to be a bit more simple since does not require code input each time.

Comment: That would be much too time consuming and would unfortunately defeat the purpose.  The idea is that rather than have teachers painstakingly write out targets which are mostly the same every time, we have a system of agreed standard targets that we use.  Teacher's simply put the code and the target is lookedup for them so they don't have to manually write it out.  They sometimes need to tweak them though and that's my problem.  I'm surprised there's no way to edit the text once it's done, or no other way to achieve the autocomplete thing that doesn't leave the formula in the cell.

Comment: @EdFearon, in that case only VBA may help - I swear there's NO solution for Excel that may keep in the same cell both text AND formula without any non-default tricks such as macro. In case the last one is OK for you (as the button that teacher clicks and has text grades looked up) - reply back. Surely I will need more exact details about your workbook.

Comment: When every pupil in a class has submitted the assessment, we sit down to mark them.  In a sheet, we have a row for every pupil's assessment. Fields include the level/grade awarded, the effort score, a teacher comment and a field for a target (advice) that they can focus on for next time.  I don't want teachers to manually type out or copy and paste our standard targets from elsewhere, so I created a lookup formula.  Now teachers just enter a code and in the next cell, the advice appears.  We then use mail merge in word to produce feedback forms and return the results to pupils.  Thanks!

Comment: @EdFearon, could you please share a meaningful part of your actual spreadsheet for correct data handling using VBA - as a screenshot? Or perhaps even your workbook or a part of it for coding?

Comment: Many thanks for your interest and assistance.  Once I realised I needed VBA, I rephrased the question and it's solved in VBA now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261549/vba-lookup-and-insert-on-cell-change