# VBA Lookup and insert on cell change

Tags: excel, vba

**Main Worksheet:**

Student | Grade | Target Code | Target Text

Jim     | A     | Code1       | This is the text that corresponds with Code1

**Lookup Table, defined as a 'name' "TargetCodes" in a worksheet called 'Targets':**

Code1 | This is the text that corresponds with Code1

Code2 | This is the text that corresponds with Code2

I need some VBA so that when the TargetCode field for any record is changed, the corresponding text is placed, in text form, into the Target Text column.  I can't use a LOOKUP in the Target  Text column because the text needs to be editable and if you try to edit that, you'd just be editing the LOOKUP formula.  Help of any sort would be greatly appreciated.

I've cargo-culted some code together from picking over other bits of StackExchange:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim cell_to_test As Range, cells_changed As Range
Dim result As String
Dim sheet As Worksheet

    Set cells_changed = Target(1, 1)
    Set cell_to_test = Range("D2")

    If Not Intersect(cells_changed, cell_to_test) Is Nothing Then 

        Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Persuasive Speaking")
        Set TargetSheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Targets")
        result = Application.WorksheetFunction.Lookup(sheet.Range("D2"),     sheet.Range("WritingTargets"))
        MsgBox ("Test")
    End If
End Sub-
```

But I get the error "Method 'Range' of object '_Worksheet' failed...

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which part of this are you having a problem with?  Do you have any code to post?

Comment: `I need some VBA` -> Use the `Worksheet_Change` event in the `Targets` worksheet to accomplish this. If you get stuck in your coding, post the code and tell us where you are stuck. Then we can help you more efficiently. See [this](http://www.stackoverflow.com/faq) for more info.

Comment: Sorry that was dense of me.  I've updated the question with the code I've got so far. Thanks a lot for your time, it's really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Const COL_IDS As Long = 3
Const COL_TARG_TEXT As Long = 4

Dim rngIds As Range, c As Range, val
Dim rngTable As Range, tmp, result

    On Error GoTo haveError

    Set rngIds = Application.Intersect(Target, Target.Parent.Columns(COL_IDS))

    If Not rngIds Is Nothing Then
        Set rngTable = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Targets").Range("TargetCodes")
        For Each c In rngIds.Cells
            tmp = Trim(c.Value)
            If Len(tmp) > 0 Then
                val = Application.VLookup(tmp, rngTable, 2, False)
                'disable events to avoid re-triggering this sub                 
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                c.EntireRow.Cells(COL_TARG_TEXT).Value = _
                                    IIf(IsError(val), "Not found!", val)
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        Next c
    End If

    Exit Sub

haveError:
    'MsgBox Err.Description
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing! Thank you.  I've got that all set up and it's autocompleting, but the only value I get is "Not found!".  I'm trying to pick apart why.  Any ideas?  Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: When I change it to IIf(IsError(val), val, val) the value is outputted as #n/a, indicating (I think) that it can't find the value in the range.  The range is named in the Name manager and the values are definitely there.  I don't suppose you've any thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: Strangely, when I changed the code in the named range from 1 to W1 (which I needed to do anyway) and entered W1 in my sheet, it worked perfectly.  I'd be curious to know why, but thank you for this excellent answer - the contribution will save many people a great deal of time and effort which we can spend on being good teachers.

Comment: @Ed Fearon - I don't know why it didn't work for you initially, but glad to hear it's working now.